# hapi-auth-cookie: throws error when reading cookies to access locked content

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, session-cookies, hapi.js

I have used hapi-auth-cookie to save cookies and create sessions.
Some part is locked and the user not allowed to access it without authentication.
When the user is not logged in he is successfully redirected to the login route. After authentication when the user clicks on the same link again it throws an error most probably while processing the cookie.This is session registration:

```
plugin.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
    password: 'hapissajafdhafdjahyfjkdgsyjasfydukfeyafdheavjdfaejmyfdja',
    cookie: 'sid-cuboid',
    redirectTo: '/',
    isSecure: false,
    validateFunc: function(request, session) {
        var cached = cache.get(session.sid);
        var out = {
            valid: !!cached
        };

        if (out.valid) {
            out.credentials = cached.account;
        }

        return out;
    }
});
```

This is my route:

```
plugin.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/edit/{courseName}/{testNo}/{plunkId}',
        config: {
            auth: {
                strategy: 'session'

            },
            plugins: {
                'hapi-auth-cookie': {
                    redirectTo: '/'
                }
            }
        },
        handler: function(request, reply) {
            var server = this.config.server;
            var param = request.params;
            var courseName = request.params.courseName;
            var context = {
                "url": {
                    "run": ""
                }
            };

            reply.view("editor", context);

        }

    });
```

This the error i am getting:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at bound (domain.js:280:13)
    at runBound (domain.js:293:12)
    at /home/satnam-sandhu/Workstation/cuboid.io/node_modules/glue/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:858:22
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:389:13)
```

NOTE: i am using nodejs@4.2.2 and hapi-auth-cookie@6.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above mentioned issue was solved by removing the validateFunc. The cause of error is still unknown.